# Compare objects within a array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array

`[{"name": "pay1","isEnabled": true},{"name": "pay2","isEnabled": false}]`

I need to console the value where `isEnabled` is true.

I have tried with forEach method but is not working if both value are true.

Because forEach iterates over each object so it will get one value at a time.

Below is my code

```js
const arr = [{"name": "pay1","isEnabled": true},{"name": "pay2","isEnabled": true}]

arr.forEach(item => {

              if ((item.name === 'pay1' && item.isEnabled) && (item.name === 'pay2' && item.isEnabled)) {
                console.log('both enabled')
              } else if (item.name === 'pay1' && item.isEnabled) {
                console.log('pay1 enabled')
              } else if(item.name === 'pay2' && item.isEnabled){
             console.log('pay2 enabled')
              }
            })
```

How can i resolve this.

Thanks in advance........

Comment: If is static why don't use directly the `if`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to run a loop.

Just find the elememnt with `name` having `pay1` and `name` having `pay1`. Check the `isEnabled` of each node. If its true for both name, both are enabled or only one enabled.

```js
const arr = [{ "name": "pay1", "isEnabled": true }, { "name": "pay2", "isEnabled": true }];
const item1 = arr.find(node => node.name === "pay1");
const item2 = arr.find(node => node.name === "pay2");
if (item1.isEnabled && item2.isEnabled) {
  console.log('both enabled')
} else if (item1.isEnabled) {
  console.log('pay1 enabled')
} else if (item2.isEnabled) {
  console.log('pay2 enabled')
} else {
  console.log('none enabled')
}
```

Comment: @NickParsons yeah it was a typo

Answer (score 1):

one way is to filter all enabled country and display them

```js
const arr = [{"name": "pay1","isEnabled": true},{"name": "pay2","isEnabled": true},,{"name": "pay2","isEnabled": false}]


const arrFilt = arr.filter(oneCountry => oneCountry.isEnabled);

arrFilt.forEach(item => {
   console.log(`${item.name} enabled`)
})
```

Comment: i dont think so it will solve the issue.